# Finding a saved file from my app in the Android file system

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, streamwriter, xmlserializer

I've created a new file using XmlSerializer and StreamWriter to persist data. From the test I did with my app, storing and restoring data using this method is working. Just for curiosity, I've tried to find the file created in the Android File System, without success. I've tried to find it with an Android app (ES File Explorer) and a desktop app (on Mac, Android File Transfer). In both case, I was unable to find the created file.

```
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(GAData));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter (FilePath);

        xmlSerializer.Serialize (writer, this);
        writer.Close ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Data saved");
```

Where FilePath is define here :

```
        // Determining the path
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        FilePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, "AppData.txt");
        Console.WriteLine (Path.GetFullPath (FilePath));
```

The last Console.WriteLine is logging : /data/data/com.domain.myapp/files/AppData.txt

The exact same code is working like a charm on iOS, and I can see the file in the File System using an app on my Mac. Why can I find it in the Android File System? Or, where is it saved if it's somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /data/data/com.domain.myapp/files/AppData.txt
```

That is private internal memory. Private as only your app has access.

Your app can reach it using `getFilesDir()`.

Other app like ES File Explorer have no access.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using FilesDir from the ContextWrapper

```
Path.Combine(FilesDir.Path , "MyFile.text");
```

Example, copies a file that is in the assets folder to the local file system

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(FilesDir.Path , "myFile.Text")))
            {
                using (var asset = Assets.Open("TextToCopyTo.txt"))
                {
                    using (var dest = File.Create(Path.Combine(FilesDir.Path , "MyFile.text")))
                    {
                        asset.CopyTo(dest);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: FilesDir is not working. I've tried to integrate your code in mine, but I can't manage to make it work. Anyway, I'm pretty sure Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal is the good way to do what I want.

Comment: @Boris88 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage which recommends using filesDir. Ensure you have the correct permissions.

Comment: I'm using Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal to reuse the code from Android to iOS. From Xamarin documentation, it is supposed to work (and it is!). The only "problem", is that i'm wandering why I can find it in the File Directory shown in the Console.WriteLine() of my code. Also, I have the permission to read and write on external storage in my AndroidManifest.xml